# meaning of parameter $1 in sql Function

Tags: postgresql

absoulte rookie question. In a course we use Postgressql functions, eg.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Raptor_lastSurveyDate1(bigint) RETURNS date As $$
  SELECT max(date) FROM raptor_surveys WHERE nest=$1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

or:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Raptor_lastSurveyDate2(bigint) RETURNS date As $$
  SELECT date FROM raptor_surveys WHERE nest=$1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

what does this $1 parameter mean??

**addendum:**

```
select * from raptor_surveys delivers this table:
```

[image]

Comment: meaning of parameter $1 is , pointing to first argument in sql function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$1` is a reference to the first argument of the function. Your functions both have a single argument of type `bigint`. Inside the function body, this argument can be referenced by `$1`.

See the documentation for more details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS

Answer (score 4):

Parameters passed to functions are named with the identifiers $1, $2, etc. Optionally, aliases can be declared for $n parameter names for increased readability.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html

Answer (score 3):

`$1` [references](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS) the first parameter passed to the function, `$2` would refer to the second and so on.

The use of `$1` as a parameter "name" predates the introduction of named parameters for SQL functions in Postgres 9.2

With any modern Postgres version, I would rewrite that to use a named parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Raptor_lastSurveyDate1(p_some_value bigint) 
  RETURNS date 
As $$
  SELECT max(date) 
  FROM raptor_surveys 
  WHERE nest = p_some_value;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```