# stored procedure with parameter in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to create a stored procedure via pgadmin4. I have a actors table with one of the columns being gender with the data type as character either M or F, so what I want to create is stored procedure where I supply the gender as a single char 'M' or 'F'

This is my code:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE actorGender(sex character)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
 select * from actors where gender = sex;
end;$$

call actorGender('M')
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to
> discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. CONTEXT:
> PL/pgSQL function actorgender(character) line 3 at SQL statement SQL
> state: 42601

Comment: 1) Read the HINT in the error message, so use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`. 2) You can't return anything from a `PROCEDURE` so you are at a dead end anyway. 3) Use a `FUNCTION` and be more specific about what you actually want to return? Add as update to question.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data)

Answer (score 1):

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=720d3298d9ee36ff95c0370ca81995bd) But I don't know how to decompose it.
`PROCEDURE` when you call it, you also need to specify all the IN and OUT. unlike the function. you can just call it with `select function(in argument)`.

```
begin;
create  table actors(actorid bigint, gender text,actorname text);
insert into actors (actorid, gender, actorname) values (1,'hi', 'etc');
insert into actors (actorid, gender, actorname) values (2,'hello', 'etc1');
commit;

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE actorgender(in sex text, out a  actors)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    select * from actors where gender = sex into a;

end
$$;
```

call it with **INPUT** and **OUTPUT** parameter.

```
  call actorgender('hi',null::actors);
```

It will return `(1,hi,etc)`
use function would be must easier.

---

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE

```
    CREATE FUNCTION getactors(text) RETURNS SETOF actors AS $$
    SELECT * FROM actors WHERE gender = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

--call it      
SELECT * FROM getactors('hi') AS t1;
```

Comment: Thanks :) what is the difference between a proc in postgres and a user function, and why would the user function be easier?
What I would like the proc or the user function to do is when I execute it, I want to supply the char M or F to list either all male or female actors.

Comment: @user2371684 Generally function, you can easily Input, output. If no output, only input, use store procedure would  be easier.

Comment: in my case, it should return a result set of the query with gender as input argument.

Comment: @user2371684 updated just imitate the manual example.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I need to understand some of the syntax though, so "RETURNS SETOF actors AS $$" what do the $$ mean here.
Then the select statement, where gender = $1 mean?
And when calling the function AS t1, what's t1 an alias for?
Finally when setting the datatype for get actors(text) what if that argument is of a single char, is there a different datatype for it?  The datatype text in my example anyways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql   
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE  >>section 38.5.9. SQL Functions Returning Sets .  
$1 check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS  38.5.1. Arguments for SQL Functions

Comment: for the data type conversion, postgresql will try to cast/conversion. when it fail. obviously there are many tricks. when lazy cast fail, then it will fail. please also check https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This @user2371684

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667540/meaning-of-parameter-1-in-sql-function#:~:text=%241%20references%20the%20first%20parameter,SQL%20functions%20in%20Postgres%209.2 @user2371684

Comment: what's t1 an alias for?   explanation: I just follow the manual example. You can omit alias part.